# Easy secure connection over unsafe network (both endpoints fully controlled)

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, network-programming, go

I need to connect client & server over untrusted network. I've considered using [TLS (crypto/tls)](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/), but from what I understand, I first need to create a create a [crypto/x509.Certificate](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate). But I feel overwhelmed by all the parameters I need to pass to the [x509.CreateCertificate() function](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#CreateCertificate) - it says it needs all of the following fields:

> SerialNumber, Subject, NotBefore, NotAfter, KeyUsage, BasicConstraintsValid, IsCA, MaxPathLen, SubjectKeyId, DNSNames, PermittedDNSDomainsCritical, PermittedDNSDomains.

I have full control over both endpoints, so I believe I don't need any expiration or invalidation support/parameters (I can change keys both on client and server at any time I want) - so I can probably skip *NotBefore* and *NotAfter* (? or do I have to set them anyway?). What should I put in all the other fields, and why, to avoid any vulnerabilities? Also, can I use the same private/public key pair for both ways authentication (client to server, and server to client), or do I have to use 2 pairs?

Or, is there something simpler than TLS that I could use? Note however, that I need to two way authentication.

***EDIT:***

I created a simple library based on suggestions from the accepted answer, plus key generation code from [generate_cert.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go) - see:

> [github.com/akavel/tunnel](https://github.com/akavel/tunnel/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Owlstead is partly correct. Your best bet is creating self signed certificates using OpenSSL. However, I would then use the Go TLS library for encryption. Below is some code that may help you.

## Creating an x509 key pair

I normally follow the instructions [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html). Summary of commands (do for both client and server):

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
cp server.key server.key.org
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

## Using Go's TLS library

First, create a `tls.Config`. One TLS config will work on both client and server but some of the options only need to be set on one or the other:

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(cert, key)
config := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []Certificates{cert},
    ClientAuth: tls.RequireAnyClientCert, // Must be done on server
    InsecureSkipVerify: true, // Must be done on client
}
```

On the server, you need to setup a TLS listener. This sets it up on port 4443:

```
listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":4443", config)
for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    acceptConn(conn) // your code
}
```

On the client:

```
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", serverAddr, config)
```

This will create an encrypted connection, but it will not verify the other side is who they say they are. The easiest way to do that is to give each server the public key of the other server and compare it to the server that has just connected. To find the public key on the other server, you need to:

```
c := conn.(*tls.Conn) // convert net.Conn from listener to tls conn
err := c.Handshake() // ensure handshake is completed without error
state := c.ConnectionState()
pubKey, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(state.PeerCertificates[0])
bytes.Equal(pubKey, knownKey) // compare to known value
```

Comment: You wrote "give each server the public key of the other server" - so, again, shall I use one pair of keys, or two? It's unclear to me from the answer. Also, why not to use the Go's key generation functions, but OpenSSL?

Comment: I would use two pairs of keys. As for why you should avoid Go's key generation function... I have no reason. It is just easier to use openssl.

Comment: But in the `Config`, I must use the same pair on server and client, no? So where to put the second pair?

Comment: No, you should use different key pairs for each.

Comment: @akavel for normal TLS implementations the common name (CN) should contain the host name. So you would need two certificates if just for the different host names. It would probably be harder to create two certificates using the same key pair then just creating two self signed certificates.

Comment: I created a simple library based on this answer - see: https://github.com/akavel/tunnel/

Answer (score 0):

As owlstead stated, TLS is still your best bet. Creating your own certificates can be done by following some online guide.

The following article lets you create your own SSL root certificate (You effectively become your own Root CA, like Verisign and such). With this, you can create and sign your own application certificates and distribute them. If, as you say, you have full control over both end points, this is probably worth checking in to.

http://www.eclectica.ca/howto/ssl-cert-howto.php/